# How do I make a random quote appear as a Tweet web intent query parameters?

Tags: javascript, twitter

**HTML Code**

```
<script>
    window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            t = window.twttr || {};
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        t._e = [];
        t.ready = function(f) {
            t._e.push(f);
        };
        return t;
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>

<body> <a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" data- size="large">Tweet</a>
    <button id="quoteBtn" onclick="newQuote()">Drop it</button>
    <div id="quoteDisplay">
        <!-- Quotes will display here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS Code**

```
var quotes = ['Simple is complex',
'Be glad your eyes can see the light',
'Your diaphragm is beautiful',
'Move move move!',
'Easy and breezy...',
'My home is space, welcome!',
];

function newQuote() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    $('#quoteDisplay').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
```

In this setting, I have a twitter button that functions and I only need to make the button tweet a specific random quote. How do I do it? Should I create another js function, or should I change some line of code inside of the script(provided by twitter dev)? How do I change it?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Currently when I click the tweet button, the content of the tweet only includes the title of the HTML. I want it to include a quote that is generated randomly whenever the quote button is clicked.

Comment: I have added answer. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

1) Find the `a` element and change its `href` attribute to point to the latest `URL`

Your `spaceman.js`

```js
var quotes = ['Simple is complex',
  'Be glad your eyes can see the light',
  'Your diaphragm is beautiful',
  'Move move move!',
  'Easy and breezy...',
  'My home is space, welcome!',
];

function newQuote() {
  var randQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length))]
  var link = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=";
  //make sure you add id="quote" in anchor element as in HTML above
  document.getElementById('quote').href = link + randQuote;
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerText = randQuote;
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').className = 'animated fadeInDown';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- add CSS links and others -->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- see id has been added -->
  <a id="quote" class="twitter-share-button" href="#" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
  <button id="quoteBtn" onclick="newQuote()">Drop it</button>
  <div id="quoteDisplay">
    <!-- Quotes will display here -->
  </div>
  <script src="spaceman.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch, but is there a reason why you deleted the line "$('#quoteDisplay').addClass('animated fadeInDown');"?

Comment: There's no reason :) You can add it back if its not causing error. Also please remember to mark it as answer if your problem has been solved

Comment: Your provided code doesn't work; the "drop it" button doesn't generate a random quote...:(

Comment: @opeoxio Now I removed JQuery dependency from the code. It is working fine now. Let me know if you still have issue.

Comment: And it doesn't tweet the last random quote as well :(

Comment: What do you mean by tweet? You should click the tweet button for that According to your need its loading new tweet in each click.

Comment: I made the change accordingly and still doesn't work, both the tweet and the drop button. By tweet I mean, when I click the tween button, it still doesn't include a random quote.

Comment: Did you update HTML too? let me know the error. Open your console and see what's there. And did you try running code here using `Run Code Snippet` ? After clicking `Drop it`. Use `CTRL + CLICK` to open link of tweet.

Comment: Ok, so from the console the error shows: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null
    at newQuote (spaceman.js:15)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (spaceman.html:33)

Comment: In your HTML see this line `<a id="quote" class="twitter-share-button" href="#" data-size="large">Tweet</a>` , I have add `id="quote"`

Comment: Yes I did that... well, the CSS is a bit mess now but here please check this out. I am not sure what is wrong! https://codepen.io/J_K/pen/QpBrrG

Comment: For your task you don't need to use all of these things. I have updated answer and you need to use it as I have done only. Later you can customize using CSS

Comment: Oh, now I saw that "Run code snippet". Yes it works there... strange, why doesn't it work in my browser and codepen? :(

Comment: Ultimately it should work well with the fade down effect... But thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Did that answer your question? If yes please mark `answered`

Comment: It really didn't solve my problem ultimately... I appreciate the help though. Could you tell me where is the mark "answered"?

Comment: Its the `tick` mark, but its useless  if it didn't help. BTW the thing you want to achieve cannot be done that way if you want to use twitter `sdk`, the `tweet` button which is visible is form the `sdk` not your `HTML` code.